# problems with wingpanel apps indicator

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I'm using elementary OS Freya and I'm having problems when I want to quit apps from the indicator in wingpanel (right click over the icon, quit skype for example), the app doent close and I have to kill it by killing the process. Anyboby else is having this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug that will hopefully be fixed in near future.

Although the menu opens on right click at the icon, it doesn't react on further clicks. You have to left click at the indicator icons in order to get a working menu.

Comment: After trying this myself, I have noticed that you have to use the *same* mouse button that you *initiate* opening the menu with. The same problem described in the original question exists if you left-click the icon and right-click a menu item. Therefore, if you right-click on an indicator icon, you must right-click on the menu item you are trying to select...at least until it is fixed.

Comment: your're righth now I've tried that way and it works.